# Permutation(swapping binary using a key order)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want is to reorder this '01110100' by a key 41325768 ,
the expected result: 11100010 , code result:10110010.

```
def perm(block, key):
    block = list(block) 
    key = list(map(int, str(key)))  # converting key to list
    key = [x - 1 for x in key]  # subtracting 1 from each (zero based)
    new_key = [key[i] for i in key] 
    block = [block[i] for i in new_key]
    block = "".join(block)
    return block
```

- so I added this line `new_key = [key[i] for i in key]` to fix the issue but the result so close:11100100
  No idea what to do to fix it...

Comment: Can you tell us what the result is?

Comment: pp = perm('01110100', 41325768) 
print(pp)  10110010 , i did the permutation on paper it should be :11100010 @yungmaz13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between what you want and what you have is the difference in interpretation of the key. For example regarding the "4" at the start of your key, you want that to mean "put the first character in 4th position" but it's being used to say "take the first character from the fourth position".

You can change to the intended action by

```py
def perm(block, key):
    new_block = [" "]*len(key)
    for ix, kval in enumerate(key):
        new_block[int(kval)-1] = block[ix]
    return "".join(new_block)


keyc = input('Permutation key: ')
plain = input('String to encode: ')
print ('\nResult: ', perm(str(plain),str(keyc)))
```

Input/output:

```py
Permutation key: 41325768
String to encode: 01110100

Result: 11100010
```

Comment: Your solution didn't solve the problem still 10110010
"put the first character in 4th position" exactly that what i meant...

Comment: No problem ,Thanks @Joffan

Comment: Can you explain what this line is doing :  new_block = [" "]*len(key)  , and the one after ?

Comment: `new_block = [" "]*len(key)` makes a list of characters the same length as the key, populated with blanks `" "`. The [`enumerate` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) yields a count alongside whatever you're iterating through - in this case the characters of `key`. Here the same effect would arise from having `for ix in range(len(key)):` followed by `kval = key[ix]`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what means but your approach is wrong, here is a simple version of your code I made.

```
bi_s = '01110100'
key_s = '41325768'

new_bi = ''

bi_list = list(map(int, str(bi_s)))
key_list = list(map(int, str(key_s)))


print("The New Key")
for i in key_list:
    # print(bi_list[i-1], end='', flush=True)
    new_bi += str(bi_list[i-1])
print(new_bi)


print("The Origin Key")
for i in bi_list:
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
```

the output :

```
The New Key
10110010
The Origin Key
01110100
```